# How to get the list of all the files(objects) in a folder exposed by an MTP device using Windows Portable Devices C++ API?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, mtp, wpd

It is possible to enumerate all the files in an MTP device's file system and then get object id's for each file/folder in the system.

My questions are:

1. Is there a method to find if an object is a file or a folder?
2. Once the folder is found how to get the list of all files(Objects) in it ?

I have checked the Programmer's reference page in msdn website but did not find anything relevant. Am I missing something ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using [`IPortableDeviceValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319461.aspx) (which you get from the [`IPortableDeviceProperties::GetValues()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388714.aspx) method), query for [`WPD_OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375704.aspx). It will return [`WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_FOLDER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389027.aspx) if the object is a folder.
2. Using the [`IPortableDeviceContent::EnumObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388537.aspx) method, you can enumerate the content of any folder objects.

Comment: It all works fine! If you think the question is good enough please upvote.